# BootstrapSwitch not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple Yes No switch that is not displaying. It is showing as a checkbox.

```
<%= f.label :correct, "Correct Answer?" %><br>
<%= f.check_box :correct %>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#answer_correct").bootstrapSwitch('onText', 'Yes');
    $("#answer_correct").bootstrapSwitch('offText', 'No');
    $("#answer_correct").bootstrapSwitch('size', 'large');
});
</script>
```

This is the console information:

```
<input id="question_answers_attributes_0_correct" name="question[answers_attributes][0][correct]" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

Am I missing something? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JQuery ID selector isn't referencing that of the input element on the page.

Change `$("#answer_correct")` to:

`$("#question_answers_attributes_0_correct")` to select by the correct ID

or

`$("[name='question[answers_attributes][0][correct]']")` to select the element by its name.

Comment: This does make the switch show, now I just have to figure out how to get the ID selector to increase in value for each answer that is built by the controller. +1

Comment: Add a class to each input you want to turn into a switch, and then use a jquery class selector:  `<input class='switch' />`   `$('.switch').`